# What does ${...} syntax mean in Angular? The money symbol prepending curly braces?

Tags: javascript, angular, syntax, notation

I can't seem to find what the following syntax means in Angular (or perhaps it's just Javascript):

```
name() {
     return ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName};
}
```

specifically the ${...}?

Is it an Angular thing or is it just Javascript?

-thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are known as [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) allowing you to essentially inject expressions into a multiline string without any messy concatenation, but you must enclose them inside back-ticks.

```
name() {
     return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
     // as opposed to this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
}
```